# Copying rows from remote database oracle

Tags: oracle, insert, oracle10g, oracle-xe

I am using Oracle XE 10.2.  I am trying to copy 2,653,347 rows from a remote database with the statement

```
INSERT INTO AUTOSCOPIA 
(field1,field2...field47)
SELECT * FROM AUTOS@REMOTE;
```

I am trying to copy all 47 columns for all 2 million rows locally.  After running for a few minutes, however, I get the error:

```
ORA- 12952 : The request exceeds the maximum allowed database size of 4 GB data.
```

How can I avoid this error?

Details: i have 3 indexes in my local table (where i want to insert the remote information).

Comment: You don't tell us what version of Oracle or what edition you're using.  The error implies to me that you're using the express edition of Oracle 10.2 since that has a 4 GB limit.  If the table is more than 4 GB in size, you can't store it in your database.  You'd need to install a different version and/or a different edition.  You could install the express edition of 11.2 which has an 11 GB limit.  I don't know how big your table (and indexes) are so I don't know whether that limit is enough.

Comment: Hello Justin is oracle express 11g and I dont know if the size is more then 4 GB

Comment: That doesn't make sense.  If you were using the express edition of 11.2, the error would occur when your database size hit 11 GB.  The error message strongly implies that you're using the express edition of 10.2.  Are you really, really sure that you're using the express edition of 11.2?  What does a query against `v$version` return?

Comment: You were right the version is 10.2.

So what do you think is the solution? I cannot install new version of oracle, I dont have permission on the server

Comment: The version and edition of Oracle you have is limited to 4 GB of user space.  If your table is more than 4 GB, you can't load all the rows.  If your table is less than 4 GB but your table + indexes are greater than 4 GB, you could load the table without the indexes (with obvious performance implications).  If there is other data in the database, you could drop those tables to free up space.

Comment: How about not copying them, and just querying them through the database link? Or if you just need to save a tiny bit of space then set PCTFREE to 0. Or don't copy all the columns.

Comment: @JustinCave Hello, we changed the Oracle version to 11.2 , but now when i execute the procedure does not insert anything :(

Comment: Sorry, the last comment went wrong this is the real: we changed the Oracle version to 11.2 , we are using a merge/insert statement in a stored procedure but does not insert anything

Comment: It sounds like this is a new question.  You'd need to show us the code you're running.  You might have a `merge`.  You might have an `insert`.  You might have both.  There is no such thing as a "merge/insert statement".  You'd need to show us the code you're using, explain the result you expect, and tell us the result you're actually getting.

Answer (score 1):

You're using the express edition of Oracle 10.2 which includes a number of limitations.  The one that you're running into is that you are limited to 4 GB of space for your tables and your indexes.

- How big is the table in GB?  If the table has 2.6 million rows, if each row is more than ~1575 bytes, then what you want to do isn't possible.  You'd have to either limit the amount of data you're copying over (not getting every row, not getting every column, or not getting all the data in some columns would be options) or you would need to install a version and edition that allows you to store that much data.  The express edition of 11.2 allows you to store 11 GB of data and is free just like the express edition of 10.2 so that would be the easiest option.  You can see how much space the table consumes in the remote database by querying the `all_segments` column in the remote database-- that should approximate the amount of space you'd need in your database

Note that this ignores the space used by out-of-line LOB segments as well as indexes

```
SELECT sum(bytes)/1024/1024/1024 size_in_gb
  FROM all_segments@remote
 WHERE owner = <<owner of table in remote database>>
   AND segment_name = 'AUTOS'
```

- If the table is less than 4 GB but the size of the table + indexes is greater than 4 GB, then you could copy the data locally but you would need to drop one or more of the indexes you've created on the local table before copying the data over.  That, of course, may lead to performance issues but you would at least be able to get the data into your local system.
- If you (or anyone else) has created any tables in this database, those tables count against your 4 GB database limit as well.  Dropping them would free up some space that you could use for this table.
- Assuming that you will not be modifying the data in this table once you copy it locally, you may want to use a [`PCTFREE`](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/PCTFREE) of 0 when defining the table.  That will minimize the amount of space reserved in each block for subsequent updates.